# Optimize COUNT(*) with MATCH ... AGAINST

Tags: mysql, count, query-optimization, match-against

I am using `COUNT(*)` with `MATCH() ... AGAINST()`. My specific query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `source_code` WHERE MATCH(`html`) AGAINST ('title');
```

I get results after a few seconds:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    17346 |
+----------+
1 row in set (16.30 sec)
```

After running the query multiple times, the query always takes around 16 seconds to complete.

Is there any way to speed up this query? Why isn't query cache caching the results of this query?

In case it's helpful, here is the `EXPLAIN` and `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `source_code` WHERE MATCH(`html_w`) AGAINST ('title');
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type     | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | source_code | fulltext | html          | html   | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Looks like the index is being used. (Maybe the overhead is that the query is still `Using where`? Is it normal for `key_len` to be 0?)

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `source_code`;
CREATE TABLE `source_code` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` longtext,
  `crawled` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `crawled` (`crawled`),
  KEY `domain` (`domain`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `html` (`html`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=78707 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Nothing too crazy in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: See if InnoDB runs it faster.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many other databases, mysql is very good had handling select count(*) queries when there is an index that covers the entire table. In your case you do have an index that covers the whole table but it's different from a normal primary key since it's a full text index.

You can see that the query analyzer tries to use that index (possible_keys) but it's actually unable to us it.

> The key_len column indicates the length of the key that MySQL decided
>   to use. The length is NULL if the key column says NULL. Note that the
>   value of key_len enables you to determine how many parts of a
>   multiple-part key MySQL actually uses

It's most unusual for [key_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) to be 0 instead of null, but what it means is that 0 parts of your index was used for the query.

As for how to optimize this? THe answer is it's very difficult. The only thing I can think of is to create a stop word list and the other is to set the minimum word length. Both these go into your my.cnf file.

Comment: `Key_len` = 0 because `FULLTEXT` does not bother to fill it in.

Comment: The only optimization for `COUNT(*)` in MySQL is for MyISAM with _no_ WHERE clause.  In that case, the count is "dead reckoned".  In all other cases, it has to scan something to get the answer.